# How do I develop a visual studio web locally then publish it

Tags: sql, visual-studio

My ISP restricts access to my SQL database hosted there.  I can not remotely connect to the database.  I would like to set up a local database for development and then be able to publish it.  (My isp also does not have front page extensions, so I can not use the one click publish)  Does anyone know of any tutorials on how I could accomplish what I want?

Comment: I know you can put post-build scripts in, like sql scripts and run them when a project is deployed from VS.  The closest I could find for that was this though http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678491.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to locate a possible solution here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/22/recipe-deploying-a-sql-database-to-a-remote-hosting-environment-part-1.aspx.

Thanks deltree for trying to decipher what I was wanting.